# How to transfer files between computers in different network?

Tags: sockets, raspberry-pi, file-transfer

**Problem :** I have a raspberry pi which has a network access using GSM based modem and it is mobile (on a robot). I have my PC connected to my home network and now I want to transfer images/video to my PC.

I implemented the file transfer using Sockets which transferred file when Raspi and PC where connected to same hotspot. But this is limited and I want to do remote file transfer.

**Edit** : Can this be done using PHP or something similar ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A relatively simple option might be to get the robot to save the images in Dropbox/Google Drive and your PC would be able to see them there. It depends if latency is an issue. Or if the volume of images is too high. The constraints on bandwidth, latency, image size etc are not specified in your question though.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for your input Mark! The files are supposed to be sent as soon as they are recorded. the delay or the latency of transfer doesn't matter much. Also, the general size of my images is ~4.5mb (8mp) and video files are of 20mb (just for info)

Answer (score 0):

maybe try out an ftp server, their commonly user for file transfer
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-for-a-user-s-directory-on-ubuntu-18-04
PS: FTP = File transfer protocol
PPS: it should also work on the piOS

Comment: @laurenx1606 Thanks for your input! Can you please give some more insights on this FTP ? I was unable to find some worthy tutorials for its implementations. Thanks!

Comment: hey, ftp is a protocol, which transfers files(like i said on top), on your server(here your pi) then you wil need a client on your pc(i am using filezilla) than you can connect via this client to your server and now you can browse files on your pi. A client is not always needed because you can acces ftp-servers from the command line.
(sry for my english)

Comment: maybe try this article: https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/what-is-ftp-and-how-do-i-use-it/